# Selenium-webdriver help needed with selecting dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to select an option within a dropdown. I cannot select with value.
How can I select state with value like CA, FL, TX,...

```
new SelectElement(chromedriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='state']"))).SelectByValue("CA");
```

My code looks as follow:

```
<div tabindex="0" aria-label="State, This field is required." aria-invalid="This field is required." aria-required="true" alt="State, This field is required." data-talos="dropdownShippingState" class="field-wrapper-item error">
    <label>State</label>
    <div class="field-wrapper-children">
        <input type="hidden" name="state" value="">
        <div class="drop-down-selected" data-talos="dropdownShippingState"><i class="icon icon-drop-down" role="presentation"></i>
        </div><span></span>
        <div class="select-wrapper">
            <label class="label-state" for="state">state</label>
            <select name="state" id="state" autocomplete="shipping address-level1" class="hidden" tabindex="-1">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="AA">Armed Forces Americas (AA)</option>
                <option value="AE">Armed Forces Europe (AE)</option>
                <option value="AP">Armed Forces Pacific (AP)</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="VI">U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using selenium with C#
Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

var element = chromedriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='state']"));
var selectElement = new SelectElement(element);
selectElement.SelectByValue("CA");
```

Comment: I tried this code and it can't select!
Thank you!